# Where does Commerce Stripe store the plans that are created on my stripe account?

Tags: commerce

I have a [stripe](http://stripe.com/) account all setup and I have created plans. In [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) I have created products, but I realised it should have pulled the "plans" down from stripe. I have also tried the stripe payment module which did pull the plans down, but it would have required a lot of customisation to work well with the roles that we needed to assign per plan.

Where does [Commerce Stripe](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stripe) store the plans created on my stripe account?

Comment: `grep -r plan commerce_stripe` gives no results, so the answer is most likely that it doesn't store or interact with plans. Maybe you're looking for https://www.drupal.org/project/stripe_subscription

Comment: I found that out the hard way. It does not interact with the plans stored on stripe.com. There is promise that the next version will make use of additional API features and hopefully that is one of them as well as the stripe coupons.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not familiar with Stripe, it looks like the `commerce_stripe` stores the details in the remote Stripe system via the [stripe-php library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php)

e.g, in `commerce_stripe_submit_form_submit`

```
Stripe_Customer::create
...
Stripe_Customer::retrieve
```

The other place for payment gateway settings will be on the individual payment method configuration form under Rules.

Comment: Thank you, yes you are right. There is no interaction with stripe other than a few things. The other stripe modules actually pull the plans from stripe.com and use them. Commerce_Stripe is only using stripe as the endpoint, the integration in minimal.